How to do parametric analysis (equivalent of PARAM_VAR) in recent versions of SCILAB
In SCILAB 5.5.2, a package called CPGE was used very frequently in educational circles with great success for creating XCOS diagrams. Unfortunately, this package is no longer updated and is incompatible with the latest versions of SCILAB.
One of the really useful features of CPGE was the ‘PARAM_VAR’ block (a simple block, very intuitive to use) which allowed you to assign several values to a parameter during a simulation and therefore to plot multiple values on a single graph.
My question is how can we do this today with recent versions of SCILAB in a simple way while remaining in XCOS?
You will find a very simple examlpe below :



One way of performing a parametric analysis with the latest versions of SCILAB is to use "xcox_simulate" post processing functionality:

Create the XCOS diagram (see my example below),
In the diagram, don't forget to Set the context to define the parameter(s) to vary,
Write a script using xcos_simulate (see my example below),
Run the script to watch the plot with several curves according to the variations of the parameter(s). No need to run the XCOS diagram before because the script loads the diagram.

XCOS diagram:

The script I wrote is the following one (I tried other possibilities, but I present below the simplest one):
importXcosDiagram("zcos file path/how to set parameters.zcos")

typeof(scs_m) //The diagram data structure

//This diagram uses 2 context variables :
//  z : the damping coefficient
//  T :  the time constant
scs_m.props.context //the embedded definition

//first batch simulation with the parameters embedded in the diagram
xcos_simulate(scs_m, 4);
clf();// clear previous window
plot(simOut.time,simOut.values,'b');


// Change z value
scs_m.props.context = ["z=0.5" "T=1"];
xcos_simulate(scs_m, 4);
plot(simOut.time,simOut.values,'r');


// Change z value again
scs_m.props.context = ["z=1" "T=1"];
xcos_simulate(scs_m, 4);
plot(simOut.time,simOut.values,'k');

xgrid();

legend("z = 0.1","z = 0.5","z = 1")

The plot is correct excepted the legend which is wrong. I don't know why. I have tried several ways to plot the curves, but none of them is OK. If anyone has any ideas, I'd love to hear from you ==> in fact, I got the explanation : CScope in the associated XCOS diagram interferes with the plots that will be launched by the script. To avoid this, simply add the following instruction: fg=figure(0);clf();
A more radical solution is to remove the CScope from the XCOS diagram.

My opinion is that the method using xcos_simulate is very cumbersome compared with the simple PARAM_VAR block defined in the CPGE package. I'm sorry that this package is no longer compatible.
I wonder whether recreating this custom block for the latest versions would be complicated or not?

Legend problem is solved by using scicos simulate with Context.txt instruction instead of xcos_simulate. No change in the associated XCOS diagram in needed.
So, the script becomes the following one:
importXcosDiagram("file path/how to set parameters.v2.zcos")

typeof(scs_m) //The diagram data structure

//This diagram uses 1 context variable :
//  z : the damping coefficient
//  T :  the time constant
scs_m.props.context; //the embedded definition

//first batch simulation with the parameters embedded in the diagram
scicos_simulate(scs_m);

// Create a dedicated fig. not to interfer with the Cscope one
fg=figure(0);clf();

plot(simOut.time,simOut.values,'b');


// Change z value
Context.z=0.5;
scicos_simulate(scs_m,Context);
simOut
plot(simOut.time,simOut.values,'r');


// Change z value again
Context.z=1;
scicos_simulate(scs_m,Context);
simOut
plot(simOut.time,simOut.values,'k');

xgrid();

legend("z = 0.1","z = 0.5","z = 1")

The Legend is now correct as you can see below:

